# Constructor of Observable and static methods (of, from,...) not available

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my angular app I'm experiencing trouble using rxjs to create an observable array.

Source:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { User } from "../model/user";


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    public GetList(): Observable<User[]> {
        return Observable.of(this.GetDummyData());

    }

    private GetDummyData(): Array<User> {
        var users: Array<User> = new Array<User>();
        users.push(new User(1, "user one", 1, 1000001, true));
        users.push(new User(2, "user two", 2, 1000002, false));
        users.push(new User(3, "user three", 3, 1000003, true));
        return users;
    }
}
```

This produces the following Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'of' of undefined

So, obviously, the static method is unavailable. I tried two things from here:

1. Use constructor and create an instance of observable (Not working, `error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Rx_1.Observable is not a constructor`)
2. Alter the import statements to match the following (Not working, error remains unchanged)

---

```
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
 import "rxjs/Observable/of";
```

---

Any ideas what I can do to get rid of this bugger?

Used lib versions:

```
  "@angular/common": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/core": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/forms": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/http": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/animations": "4.0.1",
  "@angular/router": "4.0.1",
  "core-js": "2.4.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
  "rxjs": "5.4.1",
  "systemjs": "0.20.11",
  "zone.js": "0.8.5",
```

**EDIT**
Maybe falling for some superior issue here. I checked the documentation (link generously provided by Pankaj Pankar in the comments here) and saw no explicit mention of ES5, which is my compile target. So, make sure this is not an issue, here's some more of my setup:

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "lib": ["es5", "es2015", "dom" ]
    }
}
```

None of the Versions mentioned below (or in the docs, that is) work for me, so I suppose there must be an incompatibility in my modules.

Nevertheless, here's the only way I found to be working - but unsatisfying (much load)

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

public GetList(): Observable<User[]> {
            return Rx.Observable.of(this.GetDummyData());

        }
```

To my understanding that means Rx.Observable is defined, but Observable (as used before) is not.

Comment: Isn't it should be `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'` [docs link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#installation-and-usage)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to avoid importing `rxjs/Rx`, that will load the complete library (size problem).

Normally this is the approach that I recommend:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';// Import only the basics
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'; // for static methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; // for operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

This way you can use `of` in the following way:

```
return of(1,2,3);
```

If you use `rxjs/add/observable/of`, you will be basically adding the static method that you import with the previous approach into the `Observable` class.

UPDATE: considering that this works in my local machine, its most likely related to the transcript or build process. Here is my `ts.config.json` (generated by angular cli):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - highly appreciated - that helped understand but did not solve the problem. I updated the question with further input.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps somehow

Comment: Your typescript compiler settings seem to do the trick.It was removing the line `"module": "system"` that did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try importing below:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it from `'rxjs/add/observable/of'`.

If you only import from `'rxjs/observable/of'` the operator will not be added to the class Observable. Same for the operators.

This can be seen in the source:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/observable/of.ts#L4

Comment: Thank you, this adds to my understanding how it should work. Unfortunately it doesn't. Mind looking at the Edit-section of my question?